# Why does accessing my struct slow down my method execution

Tags: c, core-audio

I'm calling a function quite frequently in a core audio callback to apply eq to my audio samples. I'm having very strange performance results in this method measured in instruments time profiles.

I've done 3 tests. The first calls the function and just returns a zero value. 
Instruments reports this as **1%**.

```
inline AudioUnitSampleType LowPassProcess (struct EQEffect *obj , AudioUnitSampleType input)
{
return 0;
}
```

The second test is actually doing EQ calculations in the function by accessing a struct containing eq parameters.

When doing this instruments reports it as ****40***%* !

```
struct globaldata

    {
        float cutoff;
        float fs;
        float f;
        float q;
        float scale;

        AudioUnitSampleType low;
        AudioUnitSampleType high;
        AudioUnitSampleType band;
        AudioUnitSampleType notch;
    };



struct globaldata global;

inline AudioUnitSampleType LowPassProcess (struct EQEffect *obj , AudioUnitSampleType input)
{

    global.low= global.low + (global.f * global.band);
    global.high= global.scale * input -global.low - global.q * global.band;
    global.band = global.f * global.high +global.band;
    global.notch = global.high + global.low;

    return global.low;

};
```

Finally I tried calling the function again but in this case not accessing the EQ struct but still performing the same number of calculations.

When doing this instruments reports it as **7 %**

```
struct globaldata

        {
            float cutoff;
            float fs;
            float f;
            float q;
            float scale;

            AudioUnitSampleType low;
            AudioUnitSampleType high;
            AudioUnitSampleType band;
            AudioUnitSampleType notch;
        };


    struct globaldata global;

inline AudioUnitSampleType LowPassProcess (struct EQEffect *obj , AudioUnitSampleType input)
{


    float x =10+(50*8);
    float y = ((10 *5) -50)- (6*40);
    float z=10 *(6+9);
    float j=60+0;


    return 0;

};
```

So my question is why does my function spend up to 5 times longer to execute when I perform calculations on struct members and take far less time when I simply just perform calculations on variables?

Comment: Your test seems flawed. In the last case the compiler will be able to compute all four results at compile time, so you only do 4 assignments in the function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the compiler just optimizes away your constant calculations.

In any case, remember that it doesn't matter if something takes 40% if it's still fast enough (and I would expect it to be if the constant calculations take 7%). =)

Answer (score 0):

Because in your first and third code samples there's *nothing* executing - first one is intentionally empty, and the third one is optimized out by the compiler since you are not accessing any memory and not using the results of the calculations (which are all compile-time constants by the way).

Comment: can you think of anyway to optimize the 2nd example?

Comment: It all depends on the task at hand, but in general - try to simplify your algebra, pre-compute everything you can offline, see if you can get away with scaled integers instead of floating point numbers.

Comment: Scaled integers are not faster on modern Mac/PCs and recent iOS devices.